# Git workflow after a pull request from a local branch has been accepted upstream

Tags: git, github

I have gone through all the steps in the article [creating-a-pull-request-from-a-fork](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-pull-request-from-a-fork). The PR has now been merged `upstream`. What is the best way to proceed and update the github fork (`origin`) and local repositories?

Currently I delete the branch on the `origin`, delete the branch locally. Then do a fetch / merge from `upstream` to local and push back to the fork. It works but feels crude. Any hints or tips appreciated. Thank you.

Local git commands after the PR is accepted. The branch on origin deleted on the website:

```
git checkout master
git branch -D branch_name
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
git push origin
```

Comment: It may not be appropriate, but in many scenarios the local branch has also been pushed to a branch on the remote (from which the pull request is made).  And in that case, don't forget `git push --delete upstream branch_name`

Comment: Thank you. but `The branch on origin deleted on the website`. That part is under control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer:

```
git fetch --all
git checkout master
git merge upstream/master --ff-only
git push origin
```

This works if you are doing your work on *feature branches* and not on your master. So don't commit/push your work on your master. (Also don't merge your work to your master.)

The "ff-only" forces a fast forward merge and so you're sure the masters are in sync without additional (and unwanted) merge commits. Those merge commits are unwanted are they are also not on the upstream.

If you are committing/pushing on your master (would not recommend it), then your delete-master approach is a good strategy, but be aware you *could* throw away something unwanted! There is no guarantee that all expected commits are in upstream/master when trowing away origin/master.

If you're doing this regularly, I would recommend to create a git alias :)

Comment: Thank you. Looks good and a bit more elegant that the current flow. Lets give others a chance to chip in before accepting the answer.